# MS Access: How to auto fill using lookup table based on the value of another field?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables:

The first table (named "lookup") holds ID numbers with two values (named "A" and "B") associated with each ID number.

It looks like this:
[image: 1]

The second table (named "data") holds two ID numbers per row which I want to map back to the "lookup" table. Basically, I enter the values in the first two columns (ID1 and ID2), and rest auto-fill based values from the "lookup" table.

I want it to look like this:
[image: 2]

In other words, data.ID1A = the A value corresponding to lookup.ID

Comment: You don't.  You make a join when you need the value in the lookup table.  That's what joins are for.  If you need to query the same data set all the time, you can make a view.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a view instead of filling those data in `data` table and for future needs use that view and the query of that view is something like this:

```
SELECT 
    ID1, ID2, 
    l1.A As ID1A, l1.B As ID1B, 
    l2.A As ID2A, l2.B As ID2B
FROM data As d
    JOIN
    lookup As l1 ON d.ID1 = l1.Id
    JOIN
    lookup As l2 ON d.ID2 = l2.Id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and edits. The above code gives "Syntax error in FROM clause."

Comment: Which version of Access are you using?